# How to mint coins on a private PoA network?

Tags: go-ethereum, poa

I have a PoA network and the balance went to zero after testing. How can I mint new coins?

I know the genesis file can define a balance, and also under PoW the miner rewards the account. But under PoA how are coins generated (actual command in geth)?

Answer (score 1):

Check on your genesis file what accounts are funded. 
When you create it you need to have some funded accounts (sealer nodes, faucet etc). 
You can then get their private key from the keystore and "guess" the password. then you can import them into a wallet and use it to transfer some ETH to some other account.

Answer (score 0):

I assume "PoA" = "geth's Clique algorithm", "new coins" = "new  ether".

In this case, there is no way to generate new ether out of thin air when the chain is up and running. AFAIK there is also no block reward in geth's Clique algorithm.

You could reset the chain and set a larger balance in the genesis block.

Comment: By reseting you mean rebooting all the nodes? I assumed that the genesis.json could be used only once per node during the init for that node.

Comment: I mean clearing chain data from datadir and calling again an init with the modified genesis.json

Comment: OK, of course that I see as an option, but all the data will lost. That could upset the users.

Answer (score 0):

as you know in poa there is no mining reward so 
you have to allocate enough ethers (defined in the unit of wei) to a bunch of your addresses in the genesis file, otherwise you’ll hand up without any ether.

Comment: I got that is one way but what happens when all the coins are used up? Then how can we create new ones? I assume genesis can be used only once for the first block and hence that is not an option for later blocks.

Comment: multiple accounts with enough eth would be a bypass.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. The problem I had was during testing all the accounts were zeroed out. So I was trying to mint new coins. Now it seems that is not possible.

Comment: indeed impossible